# DB2 Tablespace in state Restore pending

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have the problem that in my DB2 database (SLES, Db2 v10.5) my User Temp Tablespaces are all in state "Restore pending, Storage must be defined, Storage may be defined" 
When I do db2 list tablespace I get the following output (e.g.)

```
Tablespace ID                        = 6
Name                                 = USERTEMP4
Type                                 = System managed space
Contents                             = User Temporary data
State                                = 0x2001100
Detailed explanation:
Restore pending
Storage must be defined
Storage may be defined
```

Can anybody help how I escape from thsi situation? I didn't start any restore recently so I'm wondering how the tablespaces have reached this state

best regards and thanks in advance for reading this question!
Thomas

Comment: As this is not a programming question (and stackoverflow is a programming website), this question is more suited to dba.stackexchange.com  .  You should check Db2 diagnostics file for additional information about the cause, which may relate to the containers used for the tablespace.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the question to dba.stackexchange, and I will check also the diagnostics file